# Xcode Failing to create provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, apple-developer

[image]

I'm trying to release the app, but it shows the error status as in the above image in Xcode. It creates the Certificates from (Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles) automatically after I have downloaded and double clicked and it installed in keychain

Comment: I would suggest resolving the errors shown as indicated?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by adding device UDID to my Apple developer account (certificates, identifiers, and profiles). Even though we are using simulators, we need to add devices.